# Unix utility "smiley" to decode emoticons: Where to get it?

Tags: unix, utilities

I remember in the 90s, there existed a Unix command line utility named `smiley` that decoded emoticons. A sample use would be like this (the output is likely not the exact output the program gave):

```
$ smiley ':-o'
:-o  surprise
```

I've tried to search for it, but couldn't find it. Does it still exist, and if so, where can you get it? I'd also be interested in any other information you may have about it.

Comment: I remember a script that would parse [smileys.txt](http://www.textfiles.com/art/smileys.txt) from university Sun lab days, but the code eludes me too.

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't just a simple wrapper around `grep`?

Comment: @scruss: It's well possible that this was it.

Comment: @aCVn: All I'm sure is that it was installed at the Unix computers at the university and could be called on the command line. And I know that it was not just a local thing, because I had seen it mentioned somewhere on the net. But that's all I can say.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to get it running on a modern Posix system, here's what you can do.

Get the source from [this archive](https://www.funet.fi/pub/archive/comp.sources.misc/volume23/smiley/part01.gz). (This is a more recent version than the one cited in the other answer.) Follow the instructions to obtain the files `bsearch.c`, `Makefile`, etc.

In `smiley.c`, there is a function `explain`, which looks like this:

```
static int
explain(s)
    char           *s;
{
    int             i;

    if((i = fsearch(s)) == -1)
        return 0;

    PUTFACE(FD, i);
    return 1;
#if 0
    int     found = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < nfaces; i++)
    {
        extern int      strcmp();

        if (strcmp(s, faces[i].face) == 0)
        {
            found = 1;
            PUTFACE(FD, i);
        }
    }
    return found;
#endif
}
```

Simply replace the lines

```
    if((i = fsearch(s)) == -1)
        return 0;

    PUTFACE(FD, i);
    return 1;
```

with the `#if`'d out lines, to obtain

```
static int
explain(s)
    char           *s;
{
    int             i;
    int     found = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < nfaces; i++)
    {
        extern int      strcmp();

        if (strcmp(s, faces[i].face) == 0)
        {
            found = 1;
            PUTFACE(FD, i);
        }
    }
    return found;
}
```

Running `make` will produce several compiler warnings, but you should get a working `smiley` executable. To check, run `smiley ":)"`; the correct output is

```
:)  cheshire cat smile
:)  happy
:)  midget smiley
:)  salamander
```

Alternatively, since the program is a rather simple utility based on the `faces.in` file, you could probably write an equivalent in Python just as easily.

Comment: The whitespace and formatting is a mess...

Comment: The faces.in file is lines with two columns, tab-separated, so it's not much more than a grep call. That database hasn't aged well since 1991: lots of offensive stuff in there.

Answer (score 13):

The smiley program was posted to the comp.sources.misc Usenet newsgroup multiple times.  Here is the description from the Volume 20, Issue 73 posting:

> Submitted-by: DaviD W. Sanderson 
>   Posting-number: Volume 20, Issue 73
>   Archive-name: smiley/part01
>   Supersedes: smiley: Volume 18, Issue 82
>
> smiley(1) is a "smiley server" I wrote for my own pleasure. Its list
>   of smileys is more comprehensive than any other I have seen; it
>   subsumes all the smiley lists I have ever seen posted to the net.
>
> This version has more than a hundred more smileys than version 2, and
>   a more informative -V switch.  Keep those smileys coming!
>
> DaviD W. Sanderson (dws@cs.wisc.edu)

Comment: There are multiple archives of comp.sources.misc postings on the Internet.  Here's a link to just one of them (in a comment because people don't like links in answers): http://ftp.gnome.org/mirror/archive/ftp.sunet.se/pub/usenet/ftp.uu.net/comp.sources.misc/volume20/smiley/

Comment: I immediately downloaded and compiled it. Unfortunately the main functionality (looking up) doesn't work; I guess some incompatibility between those old Unix systems it was written for and modern Linux. But the “list smileys” functionality works (so I know it indeed has the list compiled in).

Comment: There's a later (last?) version in volume 23 of c.s.m: https://ftp.gnome.org/mirror/archive/ftp.sunet.se/pub/usenet/ftp.uu.net/comp.sources.misc/volume23/smiley/ . It doesn't run properly under Linux either. DaviD W. Sanderson went on to write (or maybe less charitably, `smiley -l | lp`) what was perhaps O'Reilly's least essential book: ISBN 9781565920415, "Smileys", pub 1997.